# Thread is stopped but still running (Java)

Tags: java

This is my code.

```
public class SetTimer extends Thread{
// set it on false from outside you want to stop
private boolean runSignal = true;

// sleep time
private final long SLEEP_TIME = 10*1000; //900 detik = 15 menit

PageReaderKontan pn = new PageReaderKontan();
PageReaderBisnis pb = new PageReaderBisnis();
FileListener fileListener = new FileListener();

Timer timer = new Timer();

boolean keep = true;

public void run(){
    while (runSignal){
            pn.run();
            System.out.println("Kontan Finished.\n");
            pb.run();
            System.out.println("Bisnis Finished.\n");
            fileListener.run();
            doSleep(); //go to sleep
            checkTime();
        
        
    }
}

public void checkTime(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Date alarmTime = calendar.getTime();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopRunning();
                    System.out.println("Compiling runs here...");
                    timer.cancel();
                    timer.purge();
                    return;
                }
            }, alarmTime);
            System.out.println("Time checked.");
}
//sleep between listening folder iteration
public void doSleep(){
    try{
        System.out.println("I go to sleep for 10 seconds now...");
        sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}

//stop running this thread when application stops
public void stopRunning(){
    System.out.println("Bye!");
    this.runSignal = false;
}
}
```

after the application prints "Compiling runs here...", it returns to run the thread over and over again. how is my code wrong?? please help me i'm really having a hard time understand how thread works. thanks a lot. :)

**EDIT 1** - this is the console output.

> Kontan Finished.
>
> Bisnis Finished.
>
> I go to sleep for 10 seconds now...
>
> Time checked.
>
> Bye!
>
> Compiling runs here...
>
> Kontan Finished.
>
> Bisnis Finished.
>
> I go to sleep for 10 seconds now...
>
> Time checked.
>
> Bye!
>
> Compiling runs here...
>
> ...........

**EDIT 2 - Update**... I'm using System.exit() to jump out of the endless loop and end the application.

```
public void checkTime(){
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 9);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
            Date alarmTime = calendar.getTime();
            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopRunning();
                    System.out.println("Compiling runs here...");
                    System.out.println("Application is closing..."); 
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }, alarmTime);
            System.out.println("Time checked.");
}
```

Comment: "it returns to run the thread over and over again" , which thread? You'd better give us your console output in the question so that we can pick everything up fast.

Comment: sorry i mean the run() method still runs over and over again despite the application have called the stopRunning() method.

Comment: you have plenty of run() method in your question, which though you should not, do you mean you see "Kotan Finished. and Bisis Finished" out put again and again? or something else? I still advice that you put your console output in your question. You it just print once, use volatile of your runSignal .

Comment: yes it runs everything in the run() method - pn.run(), "Kontan Finished.", pb.run(), "Bisnis Finished.", fileListener.run(), doSleep(), checkTime() over and over again although I have set the runSignal variable to "false" if the time is 9 am. sorry i can put my console input because the program prints a lot of lines.

Comment: I am not sure if you run plenty of the thread SetTimer , you may prints the Threadid in the run method and see if they are the same thread. And also, do you run your thread SetTimer by calling run() method? or start() method?

Comment: yes they prints the same. i call it by run() method but when i tried the start() method, it works just the same.

Answer (score 1):

Please declare your runSignal boolean as volatile. Volatile guarantees that the thread reading the variable sees the changes done to it by another thread just before reading it. In your case it looks like the Timer thread which is changing the value of runSignal is not read by your other thread which is executing run and hence it is not stopping.

```
private volatile boolean runSignal = true;
```

**EDIT:-**
By doing the below changes your code works absolutely fine. The reason for doing this change is to avoid any exceptions trying to schedule a timer which is already cancelled.

Write a method called:-

```
public void stopTimer() {
            timer.cancel();
            timer.purge();
        }
```

Call this method from your run method as below:-

```
public void run(){
            while (runSignal){
                pn.run();
                System.out.println("Kontan Finished.\n");
                pb.run();
                System.out.println("Bisnis Finished.\n");
                fileListener.run();
                doSleep(); //go to sleep
                checkTime();
            }
            stopTimer();
        }
```

And remove the timer cancel from your timer schedule method as below:-

```
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    stopRunning();
                    System.out.println("Compiling runs here...");                   
                    return;
                }
            }, alarmTime);
```

Comment: Or better yet, use `AtomicBoolean`

Comment: i've tried it but the result is just the same. i don't know where in my code is wrong. maybe the algorithm?? thanks.

Comment: i tried your code but the method run() still continuously runs.

Comment: @EnggelinGiacintaWongkar Can you pls paste the code which creates the SetTimer thread and calls start of this thread. Want to see if this is called in a loop.